# Create an identity mapping for EKS with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am currently provision my EKS cluster/s using EKSCTL and I want to use Terraform to provision the cluster/s. I am using Terraform EKS module to create cluster. I have use EKSCTL to create identity mapping with following command

```
eksctl create iamidentitymapping -- region us-east-1 --cluster stage-cluster --arn arn:aws:iam::111222333444:role/developer --username dev-service
```

I want to convert this command to Terraform with following, but it is not the best way

```
  resource "null_resource" "eks-identity-mapping" {
  depends_on = [
    module.eks,
    aws_iam_policy_attachment.eks-policy-attachment
  ]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      eksctl create iamidentitymapping \
      --cluster ${var.eks_cluster_name} \
      --arn ${data.aws_iam_role.mwaa_role.arn} \
      --username ${var.mwaa_username} \
      --profile ${var.aws_profile} \
      --region ${var.mwaa_aws_region}
    EOF
  }
}
```

How can I use Kubernetes provider to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a clear matching for this particular command, but you can achieve something similar by setting the `aws-auth` config map in kubernetes, adding all of the users/roles and their access rights in one go.

For example we use something like the following below to supply the list of admins to our cluster:

```rb
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
  metadata {
    name      = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  data = {
    mapRoles = <<CONFIGMAPAWSAUTH
- rolearn: ${var.k8s-node-iam-arn}
  username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
  groups:
    - system:bootstrappers
    - system:nodes
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::111222333444:role/developer
  username: dev-service
  groups:
    - system:masters
CONFIGMAPAWSAUTH
  }
}
```

Note that this file contains all of the role mappings, so you should make sure `var.k8s-node-iam-arn` is set to the superuser of the cluster otherwise you can get locked out. Also you have to set what access these roles will get.

You can also add specific IAM users instead of roles as well:

```yaml
- userarn: arn:aws:iam::1234:user/user.first
  username: user.first
  groups:
    - system:masters
```

Comment: Thanks, This is actually working. Adding to that, we need to import existing **aws-auth** config-map to terraform before updating.

`terraform import kubernetes_config_map.aws-auth kube-system/aws-auth`

Comment: Some additional information, the eksctl command adds this to the auth map:

~~~
- rolearn: <rolearn>
      username: <username>
~~~

For my use case we don't want the group in there because we're restricting some users to specific namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and created a working example of how to update the automatically created aws-auth config map for an existing EKS cluster using terraform:
https://github.com/jamiemo/k8s-eks-aws-auth-configmap

```
# 1. Find cluster based on tags
data "aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources" "cluster" {
  resource_type_filters = ["eks:cluster"]

  tag_filter {
    key    = "Environment"
    values = ["dev"]
  }

  tag_filter {
    key    = "Project"
    values = ["jamiemo"]
  }
}

# 2. Extract cluster name
locals {
  cluster_arn      = data.aws_resourcegroupstaggingapi_resources.cluster.resource_tag_mapping_list[0].resource_arn
  cluster_name     = regex("^arn:aws:eks:.+:\\d+:cluster\\/(.+)$", local.cluster_arn)[0] 
}

# 3. Create EKS data sources with cluster name
data "aws_eks_cluster" "eks" {
  name = local.cluster_name
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "eks" {
  name = local.cluster_name
}

# 4. Create kubernetes provider
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.eks.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.eks.token
}

# 5. Create IAM role and policy e.g. codebuild
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["codebuild.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "service_role" {
  name               = "service-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}

# 6. Create servicec role permissions
locals {
  new_role_yaml = <<-EOF
    - groups:
      - system:masters
      rolearn: ${aws_iam_role.service_role.arn}
      username: ${aws_iam_role.service_role.name}
    EOF
}

# 7. Get aws-auth config map data source
data "kubernetes_config_map" "aws_auth" {
  metadata {
    name = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}

# 8. Update aws-auth configmap
resource "kubernetes_config_map_v1_data" "aws_auth" {
  force = true

  metadata {
    name      = "aws-auth"
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }

  data = {
    # Convert to list, make distinict to remove duplicates, and convert to yaml as mapRoles is a yaml string.
    # replace() remove double quotes on "strings" in yaml output.
    # distinct() only apply the change once, not append every run.
    mapRoles = replace(yamlencode(distinct(concat(yamldecode(data.kubernetes_config_map.aws_auth.data.mapRoles), yamldecode(local.new_role_yaml)))), "\"", "")
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly in the eks module.
You create the list of roles you want to add, e.g.:

```
locals {
    aws_auth_roles = [
    {
      rolearn  = ${data.aws_iam_role.mwaa_role.arn}
      username = ${var.mwaa_username}
      groups = [
        "system:masters"
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

and then in the module, you add:

```
module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.5.1"
  [...]
  # aws-auth configmap
  manage_aws_auth_configmap = true
  aws_auth_roles            = local.aws_auth_roles
  [...]
}
```

Note: In older versions of "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws" (14, 17) it was `map_users` and `map_roles`, in 19 it is `manage_aws_auth_configmap` and `aws_auth_users`, `aws_auth_roles`.
See the documentation here: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/19.7.0#input_manage_aws_auth_configmap

UPDATE: for this to work and not give an error like `Error: The configmap "aws-auth" does not exist`, you need to also add this authentication part:

```
data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "default" {
  name = local.cluster_name
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
  token = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.default.token
}
```